# Visual Studio 2022 - Unable to start program, Access is denied

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to run C++ on Visual Studio 2022 and I run into this prompt. When I initially saw this, I was confused as earlier I ran it and it didn't encounter any issues.

I've tried looking online for help but they didnt help solve the issue.  A little help would be appreciated. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/obQbo.png)

Comment: I'd check if an overzealous antivirus program is blocking the file.

Comment: If it is not that make sure you did not open Visual Studio in Admin mode the last time you ran this.

Comment: Also, don't compile while you are running the application, as Windows does not allow to overwrite open files.